# RSelenium doesn't open web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rselenium

I am working with `RSelenium` to access a JSON web page. I already configure my machine to open Google Chrome but I have problems to navigate my web page. My code is the following:

```
> require(RSelenium)
Loading required package: RSelenium
> remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$applicationCacheEnabled
[1] FALSE

$rotatable
[1] FALSE

$mobileEmulationEnabled
[1] FALSE

$networkConnectionEnabled
[1] TRUE

$chrome
$chrome$userDataDir
[1] "C:\\Users\\fjchauxg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir6336_25181"


$takesHeapSnapshot
[1] TRUE

$databaseEnabled
[1] FALSE

$handlesAlerts
[1] TRUE

$hasTouchScreen
[1] TRUE

$version
[1] "58.0.3029.110"

$platform
[1] "XP"

$browserConnectionEnabled
[1] FALSE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$acceptSslCerts
[1] TRUE

$webdriver.remote.sessionid
[1] "f3bb1468-58e9-427d-82e1-c11c2beedcfe"

$locationContextEnabled
[1] TRUE

$webStorageEnabled
[1] TRUE

$browserName
[1] "chrome"

$takesScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$javascriptEnabled
[1] TRUE

$cssSelectorsEnabled
[1] TRUE

$id
[1] "f3bb1468-58e9-427d-82e1-c11c2beedcfe"

> enlace<-"http://www.la14.com"
> remDr$navigate(enlace)

Selenium message:unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"7836.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.11.298604 (75ea2fdb5c87f133a8e1b8da16f6091fb7d5321e),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'FJCHAUXG', ip: '172.16.120.129', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\fjchauxg\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6336_25181}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: cf2489a4c083409ed6072ed2f8b9eaf7

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

In chrome, I obtain the following message:

[image]

It is something refered to extensions in Chrome. I click on cancel and run again:

```
> remDr$navigate(enlace)

Selenium message:java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'FJCHAUXG', ip: '172.16.120.129', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Finally, I noted that I can't close chrome:

```
> remDr$close()

Selenium message:Connection refused: connect

    Error:   Summary: UnknownError
         Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
         class: java.net.ConnectException
         Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I don't know why I obtain this errors. I will grateful with your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `rsDriver()`, no RSelenium server is launched. I can navigate to the website and load the page with:

```
require(RSelenium)
rSel <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rSel$client

enlace<-"http://www.la14.com"
remDr$navigate(enlace)
rSel$server$stop()
```

Comment: ConCave your solution didn't work. I obtained ``Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server`` while checking geckodriver versions. That is, it doesn't download geckodriver.

Comment: What version of R and Rselenium are you using?

Comment: R 3.4.0 and R Studio 1.0.143.